# How to change a WordPress network domain

Tags: multisite, migration

I recently moved my WordPress network to a new domain and thought I had updated every reference to that domin, however I was wrong.  I searched high and low for the answey, but alas I could find it no where, so I thought I'd write this question/answer.

In my scanario, the 'home' site on the network is a simple page that lists all of the other sites that are currently active, but the `network_site_url({blog path})` was returning a link to the site on the old domain.

`network_site_url()` uses `get_current_site()` to return an object relating to the current site, and it was that object that listed the `domain` incorrectly.

```
function get_current_site() {
    global $current_site;
    return $current_site;
}
```

Dispite my efforts, I could not find where the `$current_site` global was declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The database

Initially you should update all references to your old domain in the database.  The following SQL will take care of that, but first read these notes -

- This SQL assumes that you are using the default `wp_` table prefix.  Simply change this to your chosen table prefix if you have changed it.
- Replace `database_name` with the name of the database which is used by WordPress.
- Replace `www.old-domain.com` with the name of the domain from which you are **moving away from**.
- Replace `www.new-domain.com` with the name of the domain that you are **moving to**.
- While it's unlikely, there may be other references to the old domain (in `wp_postmeta` for example).  To check, in `PHPMyAdmin` you should select the databse, click **Search** and search for any references to `%www.old-domain.com%` in all tables, and then manually update them as required.

**Important** - The example below will only update references to the old domain for the main site and the first child site.  Should you have more sites you will need to replicate the code for the `UPDATE wp_*_options...` and `UPDATE wp_*_posts` queries, where `*` is the ID of the site.

```
USE `database_name`;
UPDATE `wp_options` AS `o1` SET `o1`.`option_value` = REPLACE(`o1`.`option_value`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com') WHERE `o1`.`option_name` IN (
    'siteurl',
    'home'
);
UPDATE `wp_options` AS `o2` SET `o2`.`option_value` = REPLACE(`o2`.`option_value`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com') WHERE `o2`.`option_name` IN (
    'siteurl',
    'home'
);
UPDATE `wp_posts` AS `p1` SET `p1`.`guid` = REPLACE(`p1`.`guid`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com');
UPDATE `wp_2_posts` AS `p2` SET `p2`.`guid` = REPLACE(`p2`.`guid`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com');
UPDATE `wp_blogs` AS `b` SET `b`.`domain` = REPLACE(`b`.`domain`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com');
UPDATE `wp_site` AS `s` SET `s`.`domain` = REPLACE(`s`.`domain`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com');
UPDATE `wp_sitemeta` AS `sm` SET `sm`.`meta_value` = REPLACE(`sm`.`meta_value`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com');
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` AS `um` SET `um`.`meta_value` = REPLACE(`um`.`meta_value`, 'www.old-domain.com', 'www.new-domain.com');
```

---

## The important bit that I missed

In a network installation a `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` constant is declared in `wp-config.php`.  Simply open that file and update the value of that constant to your new domain and you should be good to go.

---

## One more consideration

In some cases `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants may be declared in `wp-config.php`, and these will of course override any entries in the database.  I'd suggest searching the file for those entries just in case, and if they are present I'd recommed removing them (or at least commenting them out), as it's much better to use the DB entries.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.old-domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.old-domain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:
[Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

And do:

```
replace: "olddomaim.com" with: "newdomain.com"
and > "live run"
```

If you need replace nowwwdomain.com to www.domain.com at first do:

```
replace: "www.domain.com" with: "domain.com"
and > "live run"
```

Then:

```
replace: "domain.com" with: "www.domain.com"
and > "live run"
```

Because else you can get issues with "www.www.domain.com"