# WordPress multisite dashboard not working..!

Tags: multisite

I have installed a multisite network in WordPress on my test server and it was working fine but when I did the same on my production server it's not working properly. When I try to login in wp-admin it opens perfectly fine but when I try to open dashboard of subsite, its dashboard loads without css and none of the links opens (every link showing file not found) while the default dashboard working perfectly fine. This setup is working fine on my test server.

Below is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pages/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# for files that end with ".py"
<FilesMatch \.css$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

here is my wp-config:

```
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'xxxxx'); 

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'xxxxx');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxx');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'xxxxx');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'xxxxx');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xxxxx');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'xxxxx');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'xxxxx');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'xxxxx');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'xxxxx');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'xxxxx');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/pages/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);


/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files
```

Please help..!!

Comment: The fact that your CSS is not loading suggests that your site cannot find it, which in turn suggests a URL somewhere in the DB is incorrect.  As it happens, I had a similar issues and posted a question a couple of months back - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174150/how-to-change-a-wordpress-network-domain

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my prob is different, as i have mentioned other links are not working showing file not found and same is happening with load-styles.php in admin of subsite.

Comment: So you are getting 404 errors when you try and load an admin page - that means that somewhere in your **DB** or **wp-config.php** there is a reference to an incorrect URL.  Check what URL is being requested, I suspect that it is different to that of your site.

Comment: Its not 404 page not found error.. its file not found error thrown by wordpress..

Answer (score 0):

Open up your wp-config.php file. Turn off script concatenating by adding this line:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Make sure you add this before:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Hopefully this helps you save the day for your WordPress installs!
But not sure the admin pages. It will solve your dashboard issue.